# how to print response json from website using puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer

I try to get google translation website to do some work for me, the website returns a blank web page with a json file. Using web brower, I can save the json file and open it in a text editor.

I am trying to use puppeteer to get this done automatically. Here is my code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false, args: ["--no-sandbox"]});
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  // Approach 1:
  const response = await page.goto('https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=en&tl=zh&dt=t&q=Edit%20Report');
  let text = await response.text();
  console.log(text);
  let json = await response.json();
  console.log(json);

  await browser.close();
})();
```

When I run this code, brower is launched, but the returned json file still get automatically saved to  the disk instead of printing to the console. What puppeteer class I should use for this task?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is an API call and the expected result is JSON, you can use a simple nodsJS or Jquery code to return the response as below.

```
$.get('https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?`client=gtx&sl=en&tl=zh&dt=t&q=Edit%20Report', (data) =>`
{
    console.log(data);
});
```

but if you are particular about using puppeteer and want to return the response. you would do the following.

Add a Jquery dependency to your project, by running

```
npm install jquery
```

Import the JQuery to the project.

Invoke the below code, without launching the browser.

```
 $.get('https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=en&tl=zh&dt=t&q=Edit%20Report', (data) =>
{
    console.log(data);
});
```

Here is the link to JSfiddle code https://jsfiddle.net/faizmagic/0h6cm1o4/latest/

I hope this helps.